# Delegates and Data Sources not working with UIPickerViewDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

I am trying to implement a separate Data Source and Delegate for a UIPickerView, so that my classes can be more encapsulated.  I have the following Delegate, that should handle when the picker is moved:

```
class LocationPickerViewDelegate : NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate {
        let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        print(months[row]);
    }
}
```

and this data source that stores the data in the picker:

```
class LocationPickerViewDataSource  : NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource {
        let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return months[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return months.count
    }

}
```

This is my picker view which is being implemented in a view controller.  I am assigning my data source and delegate as my new classes:

```
class LocationPickerView: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.delegate = LocationPickerViewDelegate()
        self.dataSource = LocationPickerViewDataSource()
    }



}
```

However my data source and delegate are never used and the picker is blank, none of these methods are ever called.  However if you implement these in the view and set data source and delegate to self, the whole thing works.  Does anyone have any clue as to why this happens?  Am I setting the variables wrong?

If anyone has seen this before, and has an idea on what is going wrong that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is about strong references. You need to store the delegate and datasource in a variable because these are `weak` variables of the picker view itself. The view controller does just that.

Just add datasource and delegate variables to the view controller that is managing  the picker.

See the declarations the documentation:

```
weak var delegate: UIPickerViewDelegate?
weak var dataSource: UIPickerViewDataSource?
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused... Where should I set these with the LocationPickerViewDelegate and LocationPickerViewDataSource objects?

Comment: I've added these in my LocationViewController with the UIPickerView in there:

@IBOutlet weak var LocationPicker: LocationPickerView!

weak var delegate: UIPickerViewDelegate?
weak var dataSource: UIPickerViewDataSource?


self.delegate = LocationPickerViewDelegate()
self.dataSource = LocationPickerViewDataSource()

in LocationPickerView but it still doesn't work

Comment: Sure, with the code you quote it doesn't work. You have to populate your *variables* with the actual delegates and assign *those* to your picker view, not create new ones when you set the delegate! If you cannot see that you have created empty variables, maybe you are a bit over your head with this project.